# How does LSTM give such high accuracy on stock prediction

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, lstm

I referred to the code [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/05/stock-price-prediction-and-forecasting-using-stacked-lstm/) to build an LSTM that can predict stock prices using only the previous 100 days price information. The model seems to perform very well on training and validation data, but not so much on the test data. Can anyone tell why this could be the case? According to me, the following might be the reason, why this approach is wrong, but doesn't explain the high accuracy:

- price has a non-stationary distribution, we should have taken a stationary distribution as input and output both

PS.: This code is given in a LOT of places, which makes me question if the model worked so well, why are these people posting their code and not making money from it

Comment: 1) This is on-topic here and gets an upvote from me, though I wonder if you’ll get better responses on the Quantitative Finance Stack, quant.stackexchange.com.  // 2) If it’s not doing well on the test set, then it’s not doing well. In that case, the reason they aren’t using it to become squillionaires is because they wouldn’t make money!